# Is it possible to access Jenkins GUI if it's in private subnet in aws vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I can access my Jenkins (amazon linux EC2 instance) in private subnet using bastion host as well as using openVPN , that's how i installed Jenkins in EC2 instance , but i am not able to view UI for Jenkins. Is there a way to view GUI for Jenkins hosted in private subnet in AWS VPC ?

Comment: If you are connected to the VPN, you should be able to see Jenkins UI on the EC2 public IP address and Jenkins default port 8080.

Comment: @czende My jenkins EC2 doesn't have public IP, are you talking about openVPN instance's IP?

Comment: Yes, every EC2 instance should have public IP address by default and generated EC2 DNS name. Next thing is, how instance security group is configured. You have to allow inbound traffic for that 8080 port (only from the inside of your VPC).

Comment: @czende I have public IP for my OpenVPN instance(in public subnet) but i don't have public IP for my private instance , also for security group i have added inbound for port 8080 from my OpenVPN instance private IP (in Jenkins security group) , but when i try to access using my OpenVPN public IP:8080 i can't access Jenkins

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can place an Application Load Balancer in your public subnet and have it forward traffic to your Jenkins instance in the private subnet. You will need to make sure your VPC route table is configured to route traffic correctly for this to work. You can use the public DNS of your load balancer, or create a custom domain using Route 53 and point it to your load balancer.

Comment: Thankyou @living-etc , i have used ELB , and now i can access jenkins console